# Switch Background Image on success() jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

**THIS PROBLEM IS NOW FIXED**

see updated css below.

I currently have:

```
$("form#FanDetail").serialize(),
                    function(){
                        $('form#FanDetail').hide(function(){
                            $('div.success').fadeIn();
                            // setup for next tab: [about]
                            $('li#about').removeClass('selected').addClass('Unselected'); // remove about bg, replace with gray bgColor
                            $('li#contact').removeClass('Unselected').addClass('selected'); // add bg, replace with red bg
                        });
```

Comment: The first thing I'd suggest is making sure that your CSS works when you set it manually.  This will eliminate the case you have a screwed up image path etc.  Also I see the 'Unselected' css, but it appears you didn't include 'selected' unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @vpiTriumph - please see update to date css. There is both a .selected and .Unselected css classes.

Comment: @vpiTriumph - was able to debug this myself. It was a problem with the css. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should post your answer and mark it accepted - future users will benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css for `.selected` and `.Unselected` is as follows:

```
    #editProfileNav ul li.selected{         /* here */
        width:86px;
        height:40px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0 1px 0 0;
        background-image:url('../img/SeleBox.png');
        float:left;
        list-style-type:none;
        list-style:none;
    }

    #editProfileNav ul li.Unselected{
        width:86px;
        height:40px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0 1px 0 0;
        background-image:url('../img/unSeleBox.png');
        float:left;
        list-style-type:none;
        list-style:none;
    }
    /*       was originally  using this and it was overwritting above css for `.unselected`                     
    #editProfileNav ul li a{
        width:86px;
        height:40px;
        padding:0;
        margin:0 1px 0 0;
        background-image:url('../img/SeleBox.png');
        float:left;
        list-style-type:none;
        list-style:none;
    }
    */
```

**`#editProfileNav ul li a{}`** was overwritting **`#editProfileNav ul li.selected{}`** CSS since it was the LAST called in the Css doc.

Comment: This actually had nothing to do with order in the css. Your LI was getting the correct image all along, but the anchor inside was completely covering it with its own background image.